# how I grant s3 bucket access with this particular role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've looked at some other solutions for similar questions, but here's the twist: I was given this and asked to grant s3 bucket for another account to put/get objects:

```
arn:aws:iam::[account number]:role/CustomerManaged/XMO-Custom-SPEG-DPM-Share-Role
```

I know the basics of how to change bucket policies in the JSON format. Do I need to create the JSON from this in the s3 bucket policy, or do I add this in IAM? I have seven tabs open for AWS doc pages but am getting lost in the weeds of what to do here.

Comment: You need to assign role to the resource you will be accessing s3 bucket from. 
Role is designed to assign to AWS resources, can perform some interactions with the resources. You can assign role to EC2 instance via role profile or ECS task etc...

Comment: @DanielHornik the role exists in a different account.

Comment: Ahh OK, so you can delegate permisisons like here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your requirement is:

- An IAM Role (`Role-A`) in Account-A wants to access...
- An Amazon S3 Bucket (`Bucket-B`) in Account-B
- You are an Administrator in Account-B

The *simplest* way to permit such access is to **add a Bucket Policy to Bucket-B**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A:role/CustomerManaged/XMO-Custom-SPEG-DPM-Share-Role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy says:

- Allow the given IAM Role
- Permission to put/get objects
- In this bucket

There is **no need to assume roles**. Simply adding this bucket policy on Bucket-B allows Role-A to access the bucket.

Oh, and `Role-A` also needs to be granted sufficient S3 permissions to access the bucket, which might be via generic permissions (eg `s3:GetObject` on a Principal of `*`), or it could be specific to this bucket. Basically, Account-A has to grant it permission (via IAM), *AND* Account-B has to grant it permission (via the bucket policy).

Comment: Oops! Just noticed that my answer was similar to @jarmod. Hopefully between the two you'll get the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

In account B, which needs to access account A's bucket, set up an IAM role that includes the relevant permissions (e.g. `s3:GetObject` on `s3://bucketa/prefix/*`). For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketa/prefix/*"
 
        }
    ]
}
```

In account A, which owns the bucket, add an S3 bucket policy to `bucketa` that gives the relevant permissions to the account B role. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountb:role/rolename"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketa/prefix/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, in account B, given the relevant IAM users or roles permission to assume the account B role so that they can get cross-account access to the bucket.

Alternatively, rather then delegate permissions directly to an IAM role in account B, account A can set a principal of `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::accountb:root"` in the bucket policy and this will allow account B administrators to delegate permission as they choose (see [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)).

For more, see [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)